# Why are there new airbenders in Avatar?

Tags: avatar

In the spin-off of *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, *Avatar: The Legend of Korra*, we learn in the second season that the bending is a gift from the Lion-turtles.

However, during season 3, there are new airbenders due to Harmonic Convergence.

Why then there are not new water/fire/earth benders?

Comment: How are we sure that there aren't? New water/fire/earth benders would be interesting, but is hardly as spectacular as new airbenders.

Comment: There were water benders that were not part of the north or south water kingdoms (swamp water benders).  Air benders lineage could be living places besides the air temples.  There probably are other untrained benders living lots of places.  Now they have a air temple trained trainee trainer to train them up right.

Comment: @cmd Yes, we know in "The Last Airbender" there are other waterbenders. But in "The Legend of Korra", there are some people who had not the benders when they were born and start to be airbenders during the "Harmonic Convergence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Raava and Vaatu, light and dark cannot exist without the other. They can defeat each other, yet the vanquished will arise from the victor.

Harmonic Convergence is where spiritual energy is amplified and, as mentioned by the Lion Turtle that talked to Aang, "before the time of the Avatar we bent not the elements but the energy within ourselves" which suggest that bending is a type of energy.

Since this energy seems highly compatible with spirit energy, as demonstrated by Wan's ability to bend all four elements due to his connection with Raava, it would make sense for Harmonic Convergence to amplify the bending energy throughout the world.

As Barry mentioned, there was a great imbalance among the nations. Since the elements, like light and dark, cannot exist without each other, it is natural that airbending emerge from the other three nations to assist in re-balancing the world.

The other three elements already exist and do not need a rebalancing, although a few people may have suddenly found themselves with new bending abilities.

Irrelevant Note: Sorry for the much delayed reply to this post, but I'm recently looking at this stack and I quite love Avatar :)

Answer (score 2):

Harmonic convergence led to great change that did more than provide a pathway between the two worlds. Since the fire nation had previously wiped out most air benders, there was a great imbalance among the four nations. There was a natural rebalancing that occurred as a result of harmonic convergence which led to an awakening for air benders only. Since Korra said this was how the world was supposed to be, a good reason for that would be that the spiritual energy helps keep a balance among the four nations and bending types.

Answer (score 0):

Once korra beat the chaos spirit the energy from it was realeased awakening the non benders history but the only reason we don`t see this happening with other types of bending is because it is natural for late bloomers but there is not many air benders which is why the air benders are the only ones who are being realized